# Writing to csv file in python in same line

Tags: python, csv

I've problem with writing to CSV file. What's wrong with this code?

```
f = open("test.csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8')
with open("sprawdzamy.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as plik:
    text = plik.read()
tester=text.split("\n")

with open("testdata_hr.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as plik:
    x = 0
    for line in plik:
        someList=line.split(",")

        if x == 0:
             x+=1
             continue
        for element in tester:
            if element in line:
                for s in someList:
                    f.write(s +"\t")
                f.write("Good" +'\n')
```

So I want to get file like :

```
    1  2  3  4  5  Good
    2  4  5  2  1  Good
```

But I get sth like this :

```
    1  2  3  4  5  
      Good
    2  4  5  2  1 
      Good
```

Comment: Please paste the full code

Comment: That is the full code. someList would be a list of numbers.

Comment: The last `s` in `someList` possibly has a trailing `\n`. Check that

Comment: Please post all of the code related to your issue.

Comment: As @rdas said, there must be some trailing `\n` in the last `s`, since you are reading from a file. And perhaps use the `csv` module for manipulating `csv` files. But for a quick fix, use `someList=line.strip().split(",")`, but i really recommend using the `csv` module :)

Comment: i pasted full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look's like your line contains `new line` characters so for remove that character use [rstrip](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/rstrip)

```
f = open("test.csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8')
with open("sprawdzamy.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as plik:
    text = plik.read()
tester=text.split("\n")

with open("testdata_hr.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as plik:
    x = 0
    for line in plik:
        someList=line.split(",")

        if x == 0:
             x+=1
             continue
        for element in tester:
            if element in line:
                for s in someList:
                    f.write(s.rstrip('\n\r') +"\t")
                f.write("Good" +'\n')
```

Comment: You're Welcome! Happy to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to think about a single write instead of concecutive writes. Something like this:

```
write_string = ""
for s in someList:
    write_string += f"{s}\t"
f.write(f"{write_string} Good \n")
```

I feel like there should be a more elegant solution than this, but it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Few concerns here

1. CSV file implies its a file with comma-separated values

```
1,2,3,4,5,Good
2,4,5,2,1,Good
```

2. Please use python `csv` module for writing csv file.

```
import csv

with open('employee_file.csv', mode='w') as employee_file:
    employee_writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    employee_writer.writerow(['John Smith', 'Accounting', 'November'])
    employee_writer.writerow(['Erica Meyers', 'IT', 'March'])
```

The output file would look like

```
John Smith,Accounting,November
Erica Meyers,IT,March
```

Read more at https://realpython.com/python-csv/